# FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 208: Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

i have just install Html package on laravel by 
composer require laravelcollective/html  and  then i run my code but it is  not success , then i add

```
'Html' => Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
'Form' => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,
```

and

```
 Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
```

to **app.php**

then I again run

```
 FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 208:
 Class 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider' not found
```

Comment: run this comment composer dump-autoload

Comment: You used `Illuminate` instead of `Collective`.

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "5.1.*"
}
```

Run `composer update`

Add the following to your providers array in config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
  ],
```

Add the aliases to the aliases array of config/app.php

```
'aliases' => [
      'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
      'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
  ],
```

Run `composer dump-autoload -o`

Comment: then i get this error "Fatal error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in E:\xampp\htdocs\icando\bootstrap\app.php on line 14" and stop working artisan command too

Comment: Did you set the `$compiledPath` variable in the `bootstrap/autoload.php` file? otherwise try removing your `vendor` directory and the `composer.lock` file and run the following command: `composer install`

Comment: no i don't touch  autoload.php file ,, how can i set $compiledPath variable in the bootstrap/autoload.php ???

Comment: here is only                   define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true)); and         "require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';"

Comment: @prakashpokhrel have a look at this [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/fatal-error-class-illuminatefoundationapplication-not-found-in-pathtoprojectbootstrapappphp-on-line-14?page=1) Question. I think that will give you the full answer.

Comment: yah , but i cant get my solution please help me out from this error :)

Comment: there are multiple things that could let your error occur. So thats why i think you should take a look at that link. Since they give multiple different answers that could solve the error. That i can't give you clear and neat in a comment section.

Comment: I use  "5.4.*" (the last version)

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem error but in my case it was

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider' not found


Script php artisan optimize handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

Though I tried and followed your(@Deathstorm) method but it did not work in my case so tried reinstalling the package as a whole and followed instruction from [here](https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/installation) now it works

Answer (score 1):

Issue is resolved by just follow these step.

Go to your project > bootstrap->cache->config.php remove the provider and aliases from the cached array manually.